# How to draw a text inside a path in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to draw a text inside a path in flutter. In android, the requirement can be achieved by using `canvas.drawTextOnPath()`. But in flutter, I didn't find any method to draw the text inside a path.

expected output:

[image: text drawn on a circle path]

Comment: you are right, it is not possible using existing API directly - you need to draw letter-by-letter

Answer (score 1):

I have created a package to achieve this in Flutter.

Link: [draw_on_path](https://pub.dev/packages/draw_on_path): used to draw text or pattern along the given path.

Just use
`canvas.drawTextOnPath(text, path);`

There is an optional parameter for `TextStyle` and other customization.